# Definition of local stability in the sense of Lyapunov requires a delta term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]
Why does [this definition](http://underactuated.mit.edu/pend.html) (screenshotted above) for locally stable in the sense of Lyapunov (i.s.L.) require a $\delta$ term? Why not just say, something is locally stable i.s.L. if "for any ball of size $\epsilon$ around the fixed point, all trajectories initialized within the $\epsilon$ ball stay inside the $\epsilon$ ball"?

Can someone provide an example where introducing this $\delta$ ball is significant?

Comment: Sure, for example $x'=y, \ y'=-2x$.

Comment: @JohnB How can I see why $\delta$ is important? What is the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ you have in mind?

Comment: https://i.snipboard.io/kqdJGU.jpg